# Data for a Specific Date

Tags: excel, vba

Objective: when I select Date in a specific cel ("G1") then the table should filter data for the given date Only.

What I've done so far:

```
Dim Topic As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer        'row counter
Dim C As Range, rng
Dim Test1 As String     'give the output by combining all the article topics
```

> Dim selectdate As Date

```
Sheets("Raw").Range("H2:I23").ClearContents
```

> Set selectdate = Sheets("Sheets1").Range("G1")

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:E50")

'filtering data as per today's date

Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "12/16/2015")


For Each C In rng
Test1 = Test1 & C.Value
Next C
Range("H2") = Test1
```

But this is only filtering out the specific date. And not for the Date I'm referring in "selectdate". I'm missing something here but not sure what.

Also, see below screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this ?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$23").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, SelectDate)
```

Comment: Use `Dim SelectDate as String`. and `SelectDate = Sheets("Sheets1").Range("G1")`.

Comment: I got it - the error was the Reference Sheet name. Thanks for you help KS Sheon. It's working perfectly fine.